# How to create users from the terminal and give them different levels of permission

Tags: command-line, permissions, users

I have to make 3 users and 1 `.txt` file.

- The first user can only read the file,
- The second user can read and write to the file
- The third user cannot open the file.

How to make this from terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create users using `adduser`:

```
adduser foo
```

Set complex permissions using ACLs:

```
setfacl -m u:user1:r /some/file
setfacl -m u:user2:rw /some/file
setfacl -m u:user3:- /some/file
```

See `man setfacl` and `man adduser` for details.

Comment: This is okay bro thanks. Can you tell me  how to test the permissions after that ?

Comment: @GeorgiBangeev `getfacl file`